# Don't allow Google Form submission at specific time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form but I want to limit the usage of this form.
Users should not be able to submit this form from 19:00 until 21:00.

Looking at the [events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) documentation there is no event available to trigger when the user opens the form (except for when editing).

The only other way I can think of is to delete the entry after it's added, but it's important to prevent the new entry from being created. Therefore an `on form submit` function does not seem to be the right option as well.

Ideally we'd have a notification to the user when it's opening the form within the prohibited timerange asking him/her to return later. Any suggestions on how to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at Form class, especially on [setAcceptingResponses(enabled)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses(Boolean)) method, which is allowing you to accepting new responses. You can use it with a [time based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timeBased()) to disabled new responses at 19:00 and enable it at 21:00.

Otherwise, you can use FormTriggerBuilder class and create a [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) trigger to aware the user of a time restriction, since other trigger can't advise your user sooner.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this suggestion. Do you happen to know a way to change the message shown when it's not accepting responses?

Comment: Is [setCustomClosedFormMessage(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setCustomClosedFormMessage(String))  what you're looking for ?